# Specified appendices and cross-referencing in text

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices, pdfpages

I am setting up appendices like suggested in the answer to this question:

[Appendix - Adding PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176173/appendix-adding-pdf), using the MWE suggested by cfr:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\headerspdf{ O {pages=-} m }{% [options for include pdf]{filename.pdf}
  \includepdf[%
    #1,
    pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},
    scale=.7,
    ]{#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand\secpdf{somO{1}m}{% [short title]{section title}[page specification]{filename.pdf} --- possibly starred
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{fancy}%
  \includepdf[%
    pages=#4,
    pagecommand={%
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \section*{#3}}{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
          \section{#3}}{%
          \section[#2]{#3}}}},
    scale=.65,
    ]%
    {#5}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

Reference to my appendix \ref{secpdf:Test}.

\newpage
\appendix

\secpdf[Short Title]{PDF on Section Page with Short Title}{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}
\label{secpdf:Test}
\kant[3]
\headerspdf[pages=2-3]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}
\end{document}
```

It correctly delivers Appendix A in appendix, but now I am having troubles with the cross-referencing. I tried a reference like shown in the example but it does not work properly.

There is a similar case, which I cannot manage to transfer on my case: [How to correctly label an included PDF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182560/how-to-correctly-label-an-included-pdf)

Comment: I did not work with `xparse` so far, but I recognize an unnumbered `\section*` command by far ;-) This command does not issue an `\refstepcounter` command, and that's possibly the reason why the label points to some other place.

Comment: You should add a `\end{document}` command ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source of the problem is `pagecommand`, as it seems to set the commands into a group, such that `\refstepcounter` does work for the section counters,  but consequent calls to `\label` can not refer to the correct place.

A quick work around is to `reduce the correctly increased section number first with`\addtocounter{section}{-1}`and then call`\refstepcounter{section}`outside of the`\includepdf` command.

Note, that this is not an option if `\section*{}` is used, but in this case labelling is of no use anyway, so I did not add extra code to catch this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\headerspdf{ O {pages=-} m }{% [options for include pdf]{filename.pdf}
  \includepdf[%
    #1,
    pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}},
    scale=.7,
    ]{#2}}
\NewDocumentCommand\secpdf{somO{1}m}{% [short title]{section title}[page specification]{filename.pdf} --- possibly starred
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{fancy}%
  \includepdf[%
    pages=#4,
    pagecommand={%
     \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
       \section{#3}}{%
       \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
         \section{#3}}{%
         \section[#2]{#3}}}%
   },
    scale=.65,
    ]%
    {#5}
    \addtocounter{section}{-1}%
    \refstepcounter{section}%
  }%
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
%\tableofcontents

Reference to my appendix \ref{secpdf:Test}, whereas in \ref{secpdf:other}, it is shown that bla bla and in \ref{secpdf:evenanother} there is even evidence that...

\newpage
\appendix


\secpdf[Short Title]{A PDF on Section Page with Short Title}{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}
\label{secpdf:Test}%
\kant[3]

\headerspdf[pages=2-3]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}


\secpdf[Short Title]{B PDF on Section Page with Short Title}{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}
\label{secpdf:other}%
\kant[3]

\headerspdf[pages=2-3]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}

\secpdf[Short Title]{C PDF on Section Page with Short Title}{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}
\label{secpdf:evenanother}%
\kant[3]

\headerspdf[pages=2-3]{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mwe/mwe.pdf}


\end{document}
```

Comment: perfect solution, works fine